# a circular plot from a vector which represents the temperature along the radius surface, which is the same for every radius

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have calculated the temperature of the section of a cylinder, which is subjected to a heat flow on its upper surface. Getting the temperature distribution in the 2D section. As shown in the following image.

[image]

From this temperature distribution would represent the upper part of the cylinder as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! What question are you asking here?

Comment: I am looking for a circular surface which represents the top of the cylinder starting from the temperature distribution. And represent it in Matlab. 

Thank you for your attention

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. Can you be more specific? Do you have an example that looks like what you want?

Comment: The first image is the temperature distribution that I generated using finite volumes, and the second image is not mine, is the image that I want to generate.

Comment: Basically my problem is that I don't know how program it in matlab, from an array of surface temperatures.

Comment: @Santiagomurillo what you want to do is a contour plot in polar coordinates then? Something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/contour-plot-in-polar-coordinates.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, what you want is to make a polar plot of your data presented in the first image. Where, I assume, the axis are the radius and angle. You need to make a change of coordinates from polar to Cartesian to do that. Matlab has a built-in function for that called `pol2cart` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pol2cart.html)). See an example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/contour-plot-in-polar-coordinates.html)

You can do something like

```
r = linspace(0,1,1000);
th = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);

[TH,R] = meshgrid(th,r);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(TH,R);

Z = besselj(0,20*R);

figure
contourf(X,Y,Z); axis square

figure
surf(X,Y,Z); shading interp
```

here it is the contour plot (in Octave, though):
[image]
and